# Android: How i can set value for <item></item> from database?

Tags: java, android, xml, database, menu-items

I populate my menu items with menu_items.xml, which is located in values.

my menu_items.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string-array name="menu_items">
   <item ><b><u>Where to stay</u></b></item>
   <item ><b><u>Where to eat</u></b></item>
   <item ><b><u>What to see</u></b></item>
   <item ><b><u>Usefull info</u></b></item>
</string-array>
```

This is part of code from MainActivity.java where i get these values between tags:

```
private ListView lvMenu;
private CharSequence[] lvMenuItems;  //CharSequence[] allow to bold text between <item></item> tags

...

lvMenuItems =  getResources().getTextArray(R.array.menu_items); 
    lvMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu_listview);
    lvMenu.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lvMenuItems));
```

I created database, and all of these stuff. Now, i wanna to put some titles from database between  tags.
Can you help me to solve that issue. Thank you. 
Tell me if u need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the `getTextArray` to `getStringArray` and it must be String[]

```
 String[] some_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items)
```

use Spanned to make the items **bold** and **underline**

```
 for(int i=0;i<some_array.length;i++){

    Spanned[] lvMenuItems =
new Spanned(Html.fromHtml("<b><u>"+some_array.get(i))+"<b><u>");
    }
```

change to Spanned type `ArrayAdapter<Spanned>` arrayadapter

Comment: I will try this, and i guess i wanna be able to add some data from database into the String[] array ?